# Script for managing server IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a jQuery script and I should explain it line by line.  I already do that and I want to make sure that is correct.  If someone has any remarks, I will be very appreciative.

```
//Here we use the jQuery selector ($) to select the servers_id which is located into  
//the delivers_id and we attaches a function to run when a change event occurs
$("#delivers #servers").change(function () {

    //Here we look if the servers_id value was changed and the value is different of 0

    if ($(this).val() != '0') {

        //Here we create a new variable sid and we stored the servers_id value in it
        var sid = $("#delivers #servers").val();

        //Here we use the Ajax $.get to get the sid value and send it by Ajax request then 
        //we set the data into the o_vmats_id html and empty the vmtas_id
        $.get("/deliverability/get_vmtas/" + sid,
            function (data) {
                $('#o_vmtas').html(data);
                $('#vmtas').html('');
            });
    } else {
        //Here the else statement, we select the vmtas_id and set the html content like in the code (value=0)
        //and empty the o_vmtas_id html content
        $('#vmtas').html('<option value="0">All Classes</option>');

        $('#o_vmtas').html('');
    }
});
```

Comment: Your indentation is damn confusing

Answer (score 3):

Curious,

- `$("#delivers #servers")` does not do what you think it does, `$("#delivers,  #servers")` might, UPDATE: unless you mean to look for `#servers` under `#delivers` in which case you should strive to only have one tag with the `#servers` `id` and then go for `$("#servers")`
- I don't understand why you at one point use `$(this).val()` and at another point `$("#delivers #servers").val()` if you say that they both point to `servers_id`
- Furthermore, you could simply use `var sid = this.value`
- You are performing many jQuery calls, those could be cached.
- Your comments are too much, you don't have to explain every line ;)
- On the other hand, what I would really want to know ( the difference between `vmtas` and `o_vmtas` is not commented )
- `vmtas` and `o_vmtas` are terrible names
- Your indenting is confusing
- Consider `$.empty()` over `$.html('')`

I took some guesses as to what you are trying to and incorporated my feedback into this:

```
var $dropdown = $('#vmtas')
var $deliverability = $('#o_vmtas')

//Listen to changes in server id
$("#delivers").change(function () {

    //What server id are we dealing with ?
    var sid = this.value;
    //Is it something we can get deliverability info on?
    if ( sid != '0') {
        $.get("/deliverability/get_vmtas/" + sid, function (data) {
            $deliverability.html(data);
            $dropdown.html('');
        });
    }
    else {
        $dropdown.html('<option value="0">All Classes</option>');
        $deliverability.html('');
    }
});
```